# How to make javascript object acessible globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object, which looks like :-

```
(function ($, w, d) {

var myObject= {

    init: function () {
        // blablab
    },
    attach: {
        // blablab

    },
    validation: {
        // blablab
    },
    submitForm: {
        // blablab
    }
};

myObject.init();

window.myObject= myObject;



})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I made the object global, so I can access it everywhere across my application e.g. re-initialize the object.
So far so good but when I want to access the global `myObject`-object directly in an `HTML`-file, it fails, and I get `undefined`.

So, at the bottom of the `body`-tag, I have this:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function (w) {
        console.log(myObject);
        // RE-INIT OBJECT HERE
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

So, the error message says: `myObject is not defined`

I have no clue why this fails. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure that the script containing your object creation code executes without any errors?

Comment: Your code is correct..
http://jsbin.com/wowekozace/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Check to see if your calling you script after your javascript file has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = "";

(function ($, w, d) {

myObject = {

    init: function () {
        // blablab
    },
    attach: {
        // blablab

    },
    validation: {
        // blablab
    },
    submitForm: {
        // blablab
    }
};

myObject.init();

})(jQuery, window, document);

setTimeout(function (w) {
    console.log(myObject);
    // RE-INIT OBJECT HERE
}, 1000)
```

Check that the setTimeout in Script tag is AFTER the js imported file.

Comment: @A.Wolff the `myObject` object is initiated in the global scope.

Comment: But OP is already setting it on global scope `window.myObject= myObject;`

Comment: Yes but to access it he has to use `window.myObject` not `myObject`, this makes the `myObject` object available in the global scope

Answer (score 0):

You set your object like so:

`window.myObject = myObject`

To access this in the global scope you need to use `window.myObject` like so:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function (w) {
        console.log(window.myObject);
        // RE-INIT OBJECT HERE
    }, 1000)
</script>
```